# Print Microsoft Report .rdlc from asp .net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, report

I made a asp page that has a Report Viewer show a Microsoft Report ClientReport.rdlc

I made this report right, now I want to print it but the print button not appear in firefox or chrome because they don't support ActiveX Control

I tried a lot to find a solution, I found JavaScript that do this and it did it but when the report is only 1 page, if the report more pages it only print one page (the shown one)

I tried to find javascript to programmatically export the report to pdf on the client side and try to print it but I only found this code in c# (Server Side)

is there any solution to print this report or export it to the client side automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Found almost similar article here  :

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC5-AngularJS-1f18da53